# Why does DrJava return a Static Error?

Tags: java, oop, class, static, undefined

I use dr java for linux to run my code. I've been running into a bunch of errors recently while running this simple program. The code compiles fine but whenever I run the java file, I get the error;
Static Error: Undefined name
here's my code; (I've got two files, Square.java and SquareD.java) 
Here's Square.java

```
public class Square{
    private String name;
    private int y;
    private int x;

    public Square(String st,int x2,int y2){
        name=st;
        x=x2;
        y=y2;
    }

    public int square(){
        return x*x+y*y;
    }

    double a1=(double) x;
    double a2=(double) y;

    public double hypotenuse(double a1,double a2){
        double sum = a1*a1+a2*a2;
        return Math.sqrt(sum);
    }

    public int area(){
        return x*y;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Here's SquareD.java;

```
public class Square{
    private String name;
    private int y;
    private int x;

    public Square(String st,int x2,int y2){
        name=st;
        x=x2;
        y=y2;
    }

    public int square(){
        return x*x+y*y;
    }

    double a1=(double) x;
    double a2=(double) y;

    public double hypotenuse(double a1,double a2){
        double sum = a1*a1+a2*a2;
        return Math.sqrt(sum);
    }

    public int area(){
        return x*y;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Whever I type `java Square.java` or `java SquareD.java` in the interactions window, I get,

> Static Error: Undefined name

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't run a class by typing `java Square.java`, but `java Square`.

<sup>*(Or `run Square`, the equivalent of hitting the <kbd>Run</kbd> button.)*</sup>

But you'll still need a `main` method with the following signature:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // etc.
}
```

Then when you type `java Square` (assuming you've compiled it) it will run whatever is in `main`.

[image]