# Interact with java file, reverse polish calculator

Tags: java

I want to interact with the java file, can anyone please tell me what I'm supposed to write on the interaction bar? I'm trying to write text.txt under the interaction block, but it gives me an error. Thanks for the help!!

```
import java.util.*;

import java.io.*;

public class RPN {

    /**
     * Computes the outcome of a given expression in Reverse Polish Notation
     *
     * @param expr the expression to compute
     */
    public static void compute(String expr) throws
            ArithmeticException,
            EmptyStackException {
        Stack<Double> stack = new Stack<>();

        //System.out.println(expr);
        //System.out.println("Input\tOperation\tStack after");

        for (String token : expr.split("\\s+")) {
            //
          System.out.print("calculating result" + token + "\t");
            switch (token) {
                case "+":
                    //System.out.print("Operate\t\t");
                    stack.push(stack.pop() + stack.pop());
                    break;
                case "-":
                    //System.out.print("Operate\t\t");
                    stack.push(-stack.pop() + stack.pop());
                    break;
                case "*":
                    //System.out.print("Operate\t\t");
                    stack.push(stack.pop() * stack.pop());
                    break;
                case "/":
                    //System.out.print("Operate\t\t");
                    double divisor = stack.pop();
                    stack.push(stack.pop() / divisor);
                    break;
                case "^":
                    //System.out.print("Operate\t\t");
                    double exponent = stack.pop();
                    stack.push(Math.pow(stack.pop(), exponent));
                    break;
                default:
                    //System.out.print("Push\t\t");
                    stack.push(Double.parseDouble(token));
                    break;
            }

           // System.out.println(stack);
        }

        System.out.println("Final Answer: " + stack.pop());
    }

    /**
     * Runs the calculation for the RPN expression in args[0].
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
          Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("./text.txt"));
          //Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("./text.txt"));

        } catch (Exception err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: write complete path of file, if `.txt` and `.java` file are in same place then just use `text.txt`. rest all is ok

Comment: @jackjay   I tried text.txt but it give me an error saying "Static Error: Undefined name 'text.txt' " Thanks though

Comment: also  `import java.util.Scanner;` at the top as you are using `Scanner` class.

Comment: What do you mean by "interact with the java file" and what is "interaction block"? Are you using some kind of IDE?

Comment: @jackjay    Still getting same error

Comment: @yeputons no, if you look at the bottom left corner on dr. java, you'll see an interaction tab..usually we use simple output tab to get the input and output

Comment: @VishwajeetSingh Please mention that you use DrJava, as it's important for the question. In the meantime, check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546071/why-does-drjava-return-a-static-error) and provide the exact copy of your interaction session (if I understand correctly, you should be able to copy it verbatim).

Comment: can you tell us how you are running this file in `drjava`. Also you should have mentioned that earlier.

Comment: @yeputons jackjay Now, I can run the file but it only prints 0                                                Welcome to DrJava.  Working directory is C:\csce\homework 3
> java RPN
0
>

Comment: I wrote java RPN(which is the file's name) but it only prints 0